# AngularJS - Need help displaying current length of string in bound text input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started with Angular a couple days ago so simple stuff still occasionally gets the best of me. I'm trying to show the current character count of a textarea. I thought surely this should work:

```
<textarea ng-model="mystring"></textarea>
<br>
<span> {{mystring.length()}} </span>
```

It doesn't work at all.. But why? And how do I accomplish this?

If I remove ".length()" the content of the textarea is showing up like it should so the binding is obviously working...

EDIT:
So it works in chrome etc but not in IE, or more specifically, the embedded browser control in a .Net winform. hooray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net browser control acts like IE7 by default so lots of things don't really work.
In an attempt to remedy this I added a registry entry as indicated in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730.aspx) to force the browser to act like IE9 but still had the same problem with string.length in the expression as well as a new *"object doesn't support this action"* error being thrown.

At this point I gave up and decided to use [this WebKitdotNet](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) control. It adds 30 or so MB to my install size but it actually works without having to change a lot of javascript or muck about in the registry.

Answer (score 20):

The length of a string is a property in javascript. So this should work

```
<span> {{mystring.length}} </span>
```

Comment: You're right, and that is what I expected to work. Turns out it's only not working in this embedded browser control (IE pretty much). Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try it with property access as well? (Your example seems to call the length() method, which should yield an error.)

Comment: Problem is that after page was loaded the value 0 from  {{mystring.length}} variable will be invisible.